# SwiftUI: How do I position a button x points above a sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to recreate a Maps-style UI with a persistent bottom sheet and controls fixed above.

[Apple Maps UI with controls above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxS9o.gif)

☝️ Example here, the "Look Around" binoculars button and AQI from Apple Maps follow the movement of the sheet.

I've got my sheet set up but I'm curious what the approach for this would be?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HomeView()
                .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                    ActivityView()
                        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large, .height(80)])
                        .presentationCornerRadius(Constants.cornerRadius)
                        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your purpose, it is recommended to utilize a custom SheetView. The following example demonstrates the customization of a SheetView with transitions and animations:

Hope it helps you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
    @State var isShowCustomSheetView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    isShowCustomSheetView.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Custom Sheet View")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            if isShowCustomSheetView {
                CustomSheetView()
                    .frame(height: 400)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}

struct CustomSheetView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "binoculars.fill")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.dust.fill")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 5)
                    .padding(.top)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.6))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SheetView()
    }
}
```

[image]